# Swipe cause GetMouseButtonDown(0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, swipe

I have a script that recognizes [swiping](https://gist.github.com/Fonserbc/ca6bf80b69914740b12da41c14023574) input. When I now start a swipe, it also triggers `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`. Can you tell me how to delete `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` that comes from the swipe?

With that swipe the game gets paused. (with `Time.timeScale = 0f;`) 
After resume, the action which was triggered from `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` before pausing the game goes on.

My Ideas: Work with `TouchPhase.Stationary` or look for short tap?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you can either:

1. Call [`Input.ResetInputAxes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.ResetInputAxes.html); it will clear all input flags for one frame.
2. Set a flag that a swipe was handled, and check for it when checking for `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` elsewhere.

Both will require ensuring that the swipe detection happens **before** you check for `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`.

One way of ensuring it, is by using Unity's [script execution order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work... can you give me an example?

Comment: Which part of it do you need an example for?

Comment: Just got it :) I changed Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) to Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0). Will look into it later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using Input class at all, it causes many problems, better have separate RaycastTarget on UI with Script implementing IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, that will ensure only one RaycastTarget at the moment is handling your touches. Input.GetMouseButton will return true even if some RaycastTarget already should have consumed your events.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the IPointerClickHandler documentation soon. I give some feedback.